# File path php , unlink method

Tags: php, path, unlink

I am trying to delete pictures from a file with the unlink method.

I couldent make the unlick method work with a relativ path so I tried it with an absolute one.

Here is the code:

```
echo '<td><img src="images/' , $tableau[$i] , '" /></a></td>',
"<td><form method=post>
 <input type=submit name=delete value=Supprimer>
 </form></td>";

 $filepath='\images\ '.$tableau[$i].'';
 $path=dirname(__FILE__) . $filepath ;

 echo $path;

if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
  unlink ($path);
}
```

But this codes gives:

```
D:\logiciels\XAMPP\htdocs\upload-test\images\ 1.jpg
Warning: unlink(D:\logiciels\XAMPP\htdocs\upload-test\images\ 1.jpg):   No  such file or directory in D:\logiciels\XAMPP\htdocs\upload-test\test.php on line 62
```

Why is it comparing with the test.php file path when I put an absolute one?

Then I tried something more simple: just looking if the file exists:

```
<?php
     $filepath='\images\ 1.jpg';
     $filename=dirname(__FILE__) . $filepath ;

     echo $filename;

     if (is_file($filename)) {

       echo 'File exists'; 

     } else {
       echo 'File does not exist';
      }
      ?>
```

And I get this:

```
D:\logiciels\XAMPP\htdocs\upload-test\images\ 1.jpg File does not exist
```

But the file really exists and I can execute it in Windows with the same path.

So I can't get whats the problem!

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: $filepath='\images\ 1.jpg'; - remove space sign before 1.jpg!

Answer (score 0):

Try by removing `space` like

```
<?php
     $filepath='\images\1.jpg';
     $filename=dirname(__FILE__) . $filepath ;

     echo $filename;

     if (is_file($filename)) {

       echo 'File exists'; 

     } else {
       echo 'File does not exist';
      }
      ?>
```

Comment: yes that was a first mistake, and now the file "exists". But I still can't echo  '<img src=" '.$path.' "/>'; and get the images to appear ( I have a broken link) but i can still execute the path in Windows and get it opend.

Comment: what you mean?I didnt get

Comment: The problem is that I still cant echo the image with the absolute path even if the path seems to exist.

Comment: Try relative path of image

Answer (score 0):

Now here we are:

```
if (is_file($path)) {

   echo 'File exists'; 

} else {
   echo 'File does not exist';
  }

  echo '<img src=" '.$path.' "/>';
```

And I get a broken link with no Image display beside "File exists"